# Scan shared object inclusions at runtime

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, inclusion, readelf

I am working on a C program (under Linux ) that relies on shared libraries as plugins.

I provide each plugin with several functions from a static library of mine. In order to change the workflow of my program, I need to know at runtime whether a plugin is going to call a certain function included from the aforementioned library.

What I need is the C equivalent of:

```
readelf -a ${PLUGIN_NAME} | grep ${FUNCTION_NAME}
```

Is that possible to exploit the `<dlfcn.h>` library in order to achieve that ? Needless to say, I prefer not executing the oneliner above in a `system()` call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [LibELF](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) which allows you to manipulate ELF binaries (i.e. read sections). Very nice examples you can find [here](http://people.freebsd.org/~jkoshy/download/libelf--/article.html).